# I heard/saw you [verb]ing

Tags: грамматика

How do you construct a sentence like `I heard you talking` or maybe `I saw you walking`?

Comment: Explaining the difference between "I saw you talk to him" and "I saw you talking to him"we usually use different conjunctions.Я видел, *что* ты разговаривал с ним.and Я видел,  *как* ты разговаривал с ним. We build a sentence with a subordinate clause.

Comment: With some verbs we can use a noun. I found him reading. Я застал его за чтением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straight-forward translation:

> - **I heard you talking.** - Я слышал, как ты разговаривала.
> - **I saw you walking.** - Я виделa, как ты шёл.

In a spoken speech [как] could be dropped, especially when English participle has some dependent words:

> - **I heard you talking on the phone.** - Я слышал, ты разговаривала по телефону.
> - **I saw you walking in the park.**  - Я видела, ты гулял в парке.

You can also use Russian participles:

> - **I saw you talking.** - Я видел тебя разговаривающей.
> - **I saw you walking.** - Я видел тебя гуляющим.
> - However, *"Я **слышал** тебя разговаривающей."* sounds unnatural to me.

Be careful when some expressions have idiomatic meaning:

> - **Я слышала, ты гулял.** *"Я слышала"* could mean *"I heard a rumour".* *"Он гуляет"* could mean *"He is a playboy / goes around."* The participles *"гуляющий"* and *"гулящий"* have distinctly different meanings,

Comment: Complex object shouldn't be translated with the present participle, it's considered like a "bad translation "

Comment: Гулящий isn't a participle, it can be an adjective or a noun.

Comment: @V.V. _"Я видел тебя гулявшей в парке?"_ This is using past participle. Is it considered better style, than present participle?

Comment: Sorry, the most common translators' mistake is using a calque, a loan translation.